Show that : $\sqrt{[x]\cdot \{x\}} +\sqrt{x \cdot \{x\}} + \sqrt{[x]\cdot x} \leq 2x$
Show that for any positive real number $x$ the inequality holds:
$\sqrt{[x]\cdot \{x\}} +\sqrt{x \cdot \{x\}} + \sqrt{[x]\cdot x} \leq 2x$
where by $[a], \{a\}$ we mean the whole par and fractional part respectively of the real number $a.$
My idea
I'm going to use AM-GM to show that $\sqrt{[x]\cdot \{x\}} \leq \frac{[x] + \{x\}}{2}$
$\sqrt{x \cdot \{x\}} \leq \frac{x + \{x\}}{2}$
$\sqrt{[x]\cdot x} \leq \frac{[x]+ x}{2}$
By adding them up we get that
$\sqrt{[x]\cdot \{x\}} +\sqrt{x \cdot \{x\}} + \sqrt{[x]\cdot x} \leq \frac{2x+2[x]+2\{x\}}{2}= x+[x]+\{x\}=2x$, which concludes our demonstration.
I put this as a solution-verification because I'm unsure if I can use AM-GM with whole and fractional parts, even though $x$ is a positive real number.
I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

AM-GM inequality works for nonnegative real numbers, so this is just fine.

@ajotatxe Yes it is

To be more general, for $a,b\ge 0$ we have
$$
\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{a(a+b)}+\sqrt{b(a+b)}\le \left(\frac12+\sqrt{2}\right)(a+b). 
$$
Since
$$
\sqrt{ab}\le\frac{a+b}{2},\ \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\le \sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{a+b}. 
$$
Take $a=[x],b=\{x\}$ to prove your inequality.

Thank you so much for your answer! So my solution is right, no?

@IONELABUCIU Yes it is right!

Alternatively, you can recognize the scalar product and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$\left|\langle u,v\rangle\right|\le\|u\|\cdot\|v\|$$for the vectors $$u=\left(\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor},\sqrt{\{x\}},\sqrt x\right),v=\left(\sqrt{\{x\}},\sqrt x,\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right)$$ and the Euclidean norm: $$\sqrt{(x_1,x_2,x_3)}=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}.$$$\begin{aligned}\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor \{x\}}+\sqrt{x\{x\}}+\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor x}&=\left\langle\left(\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor},\sqrt{\{x\}},\sqrt x\right),\left(\sqrt{\{x\}},\sqrt x,\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right)\right\rangle\\&\le\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}+x}\sqrt{\{x\}+x+\lfloor x\rfloor}\\&=\sqrt{2x}{\sqrt 2x}\\&=2x\end{aligned}$
